# paddingBottom not working in Lollipop (API 21) devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, padding

I am trying to add space between line of `EditText` and text.
When I add:

```
android:paddingBottom="20dp"
```

It is not working for Android Lollipop (API 21) devices. It is working fine on Android Pie (API 28).

layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/loginUsernameEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/username_icon"
        android:drawablePadding="18dp"
        android:lastBaselineToBottomHeight="32dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: add layout xml and some screen shot

Comment: Please read **how to create [mcve]**

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: @MalwinderSingh for me your code is working file here is the **[output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaO4n.png)**

Comment: @NileshRathod Have you tried running it? I have tried running it on Samsung device running API 21. It is not working on it.

Comment: Padding is not what you need. Cause bottomline is part of view. When you set padding, you change space between view content and it's bottom border.

Comment: What should I use then? I have also used                 `android:lastBaselineToBottomHeight="32dp"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this and it will work :)

```
android:padding="10dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please put below code for space between line of EditText and text. It works for me.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/edtFName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:drawablePadding="18dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="@string/hint_username"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textHeadSignup" />
```